# Windows forms to WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working on code refactoring from Windows Forms to WPF using MVVM pattern and bindings.

My Windows Form code:

```
searchCriteriaListBox.Items.Add("Cat");
```

My WPF XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="288" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1042" />
```

How do I implement same 'Add' action using WPF bindings?

Comment: I don't think one line of code is enough for us to be able to tell you how best to convert this...

Answer (score 3):

Set DataContext of the Page/Window/UserControl (what ever is at root level), to ViewModel.

Create property `Items` in ViewModel.

use following as binding for searchCriteriaListBox

```
 {Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}

<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="288" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1042" />
```

In the view model, put an AddItemCommand.

In the AddItemCommand.Execute, add item to Items collection

Use [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) for bits of reusable items, and read [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Bind your Listbox to an observable collection, then simply add/remove items from this collection to update, you shouldn't really be adding data to the box in xaml.

Have a look at this video, I found it very useful when learning mvvm -  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKfpvs7ZIyo